# Stack page jams/hangs on Android photo

Tags: bug, uploader

I tried to upload a mineral ID request to [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com). It's probably an 8 megapixal image. Stack reloads the image upload progress button to zero again and again. It can't upload and there is no error/status message after 5 minutes of the upload button not doing anything.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using, including versions? What's the image file format and size?

Comment: How big is the file? Imgur only accepts files that are 2MB or smaller.

Comment: it's chrome on android 6.01 it's a raw image file, i thought that imgur could compress big pics. that's probably the issue, although there should be a size error message. thanks

Comment: imgur itself can, not their API.

Comment: RAW files can't be displayed in web browsers. Convert it to JPEG, PNG, or GIF as appropriate. Then upload.